# sqlalchemy filter one result set multiple times into distinct results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working with sqlalchemy/python for the first time. it's fun so far. I have a single query that I want to split out into separate tables based on the original result set

this is the goal

```
base_table
id - val1 - val2 - class
1    xyc  - abc  - 1
2    lmo  - nmc  - 1
3    tre  - abc  - 2
4    hyu  - pqa  - 2

generate two new tables from the original
class_1
id - val1 - val2 - class
1    xyc  - abc  - 1
2    lmo  - nmc  - 1

class_2
id - val1 - val2 - class
3    tre  - abc  - 2
4    hyu  - pqa  - 2
```

pseudo code

```
select * from remote_source into base_table

select * from base_table into class_1 where class = 1
select * from base_table into class_1 where class = 2
```

I already have the SQL built that contains all the data that will go into the base_table. I just not sure how to separate the base table data. here is the actual code that I have (I have hashed out the sensitive stuff but that works)

```
    # necessary imports to drive the db recordset
import urllib

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import pandas

# section 01
#    relies on:
#        none
#    description
#        these are the database string variables
my_db_server = '######################'
my_db_driver = 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0'
my_db_catalog = '######################'
my_db_user = '######################'
my_db_pwd = '######################'

#section 02:
#    relies on: 
#        section 01
#    description: this is the setup for the odbc string
db_string = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={" + my_db_driver + "}" + \
                              ";SERVER=" + my_db_server + \
                              ";DATABASE=" + my_db_catalog + \
                              ";UID=" + my_db_user + \
                              ";PWD=" + my_db_pwd)

#section 03
#    relies on:
#        section 02
#    description:
#        this is the engine definition. it will be used in any SQL that I have to run
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % db_string,echo = False)
connection = engine.connect()

#section 04
#    relies on: 
#        none
#    description: 
#        here are the various SQL statements stored in strings that I can use later
my_sql_estimate_data = text("select * from analytics.eo.func_EstimateData(:my_estimate)")

#section 05
#    relies on: 
#        sections 03, 04
#    description: 
#        this is the first data fetch
result = connection.execute(my_sql_estimate_data, my_estimate='3066').fetchall()

for row in result:
    print row

connection.close()
```

one idea I had was to build a in-memory table using a second engine

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
```

then use the metadata collection to build the tables I need but I am still stuck with how to filter the base_table for the inserts. the reason that I want to have a base table is that I would have to make a single DB call rather than multiple thereby improved user performance and reducing db work.

I am not looking for someone to write the code for me... I want to learn it for myself, but some ideas as to what to look at for the code I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be feasible to do all of the filtering in Pandas then write to the DB from there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did find a solution. I was doing things the hard way. I was thinking that I had to make a model that I could load with data then query based on the "class" column. The better way was to use the dataframe that I already had. Below is the code that I used to get what I needed. The output form the db function that I wrote has more columns than I needed for this frame so I had to grab only the columns that I wanted and the apply the filtering.

```
hostreqs = df[['itemid','quantity','FID','primaryFacility','environment','class']]
hostreqs = hostreqs[hostreqs['class'] == 'hostReqs']
hostreqs = hostreqs[['FID','primaryFacility','environment','itemid','quantity']]
```

there might be a cleaner way and I an certainly open to suggestions being new to this language. The thing that I would like to do is to add the filter to the first df slice instead of having a second step but that would only be nice since I have code that works now. Thanks for your suggestion, toasteez.

**update**
I did find a better way to do the above code
here is the last update. I did find the way to condense the above code to a single line:

```
df_hostreqs = df_estimate_details_base.loc[df_estimate_details_base['class'] == 'hostReqs',['FID','primaryFacility','environment','itemid','quantity']]
```

I am fine with making a new dataframe. this way I am always going back original dataframe for the new one pulling only the columns I want